# Spring RabbitMQ - Getting ClassCastException in MessageListener

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I am getting ClassCastException from AMQP internals while using Spring RabbitMQ. We found this in application logs on production and were not able to reproduce this, but it's a real pain for us. 
Basically, it seems like the entire stack fails once this happens, because then we see invalid DeliveryTag being sent on that channel, which results in RabbitMQ closing this channel.

We are using AMQPClient 5.4.3 and SpringRabbit 2.1.2, RabbitMQ caching mode is Connection (because of HAProxy and failover), ACK mode is manual, Publisher returns are enabled and Publisher Confirms as well.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQImpl$Channel$OpenOk cannot be cast to com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQImpl$Confirm$SelectOk
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.confirmSelect(ChannelN.java:1552)
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.confirmSelect(ChannelN.java:52)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.doCreateBareChannel(CachingConnectionFactory.java:658)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createBareChannel(CachingConnectionFactory.java:649)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.getCachedChannelProxy(CachingConnectionFactory.java:608)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.getChannel(CachingConnectionFactory.java:499)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.access$1600(CachingConnectionFactory.java:100)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$ChannelCachingConnectionProxy.createChannel(CachingConnectionFactory.java:1331)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:1967)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1935)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.send(RabbitTemplate.java:889)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(RabbitTemplate.java:955)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(RabbitTemplate.java:948)
at net.homecredit.lisa.messaging.amqp.SaveApplicationResponseProducer.sendResponse(SaveApplicationResponseProducer.kt:40)
at net.homecredit.lisa.messaging.amqp.SaveApplicationConsumer.onReceiveRequestMessage(SaveApplicationConsumer.kt:87)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor372.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:170)
at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:120)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.HandlerAdapter.invoke(HandlerAdapter.java:49)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:190)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:127)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1521)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.actualInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1444)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1431)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1410)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:848)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:832)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$700(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:78)
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1073)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

This is complete mystery for me. 
Does anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: Do you know what leads to this ? Any environment issue , load , network blips etc.

Comment: I suggest you ask this question on the rabbitmq-users Google group.

Comment: As for the status during the incident - there is nothing special, no exceptions in logs before, no pressure, rabbit seems healthy.

Answer (score 0):

The RabbitMQ client can be configured to check the response type for RPC via [`channelShouldCheckRpcResponseType`](https://rabbitmq.github.io/rabbitmq-java-client/api/current/com/rabbitmq/client/ConnectionFactory.html#setChannelShouldCheckRpcResponseType(boolean)), see also https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-java-client/issues/708.